# Remove class on div from empty.xml layout

Tags: layout, magento2.2, css, xml, html

I am running Magento 2.2. I have custom HTML I want to add to a CMS page. After navigating to the page where this HTML resides, the content is automatically displayed inside a div with class page-wrapper. Then inside that div there is a main tag with an ID of maincontent and classes of page-main and padding-bottom-0. All I want to do is show the custom HTML in the content area of the cms page inside the body of what is loaded. I do not want to have the other elements. I don't know where they are coming from and their CSS is manipulating my custom HTML, which is what I am trying to avoid. The design of the cms page is set to the empty default magento design, which I thought would be empty, but apparently it is not. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you try to set design layout is "Empty".

Comment: Yes, it is set to the blank magento theme with layout empty.

Comment: You need to calm down and start reading the instructions ;) [Layout instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155915)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of messing around with the layout files, I just added custom CSS inside style tags with the html editor inside the magento 2 page design area. Then Added custom js with a script tag in the same editor that selected the divs that were already there and removed their css classes. The divs are still there which is not a problem in my case as it was only their css classes that were giving me problems. Thanks for your time and responses.

The script looks like this.

var maincontent = document.querySelector("#maincontent > div.columns.container.offset-0")
    maincontent.classList.remove("columns", "container", "offset-0");